# Performance issues Advantage-Database-Server 10.1 - windows 7 client - virtual windows server 2008

Tags: advantage-database-server

I have some performance issues with ADS 10.1 after changing the network.

Let me explain:

Old configuration of the network:

Server
-   Server2003R2
-   Processor: Intel XEON 5130, 2 GHZ
-   4 GB RAM
-   ADS 7.01

Workstation(s)
-   Intel 2160, 1,8 Ghz
-   2 GB RAM

New situation

Server:
-   Server 2008R2 SP1
-   Intel XEON E5530 2,4 Ghz
-   14 GB RAM
-   ADS 10.10.0.28
-   Runs in virtual environment on ESXi server version 5.0.0

Workstation(s)
-   Windows 7
-   I3-2120 3.3 ghz
-   8 gb RAM

Our application (built in VO 2.7) is approximately 3 times slower in new configuration.
Has anyone an idea how this is possible?
I already disabled SMB2 on workstations.

Kind regards,

Erik

Answer (score 1):

We just solved a similar issue for one of our clients. It turns out the virtual NIC speed was causing the issue.  We had our customer bump the speed to gigabit and now they are working at a reasonable speed.